# Relationship with cross reference table

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have 3 tables: `books`, `categories` and `book_category`.

`book_category` is the cross reference table. It has this sctructure:
`book_id, category_id`

I need to output categories (as checkboxes) on Create page of book model.
It works if I do it like that:

```
// Book Model
public function getCategoriesOptions($value, $formData)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $list = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $list[$category->id] = $category->name;
    }
    return $list;
}
```

But categories checked at creation **are not** checked in Preview, Update pages. In `book_category` table all checked categories are saving. The problem is with relationships, I think.

I created model for `book_category` table. As a result, there are 3 models:
`Book, Category, BookCategory`. How to implement relationships between them?

Obviously, `Book` can have many categories, therefore in `Book` model I wrote:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'categories' => 'mark\myplugin\Models\Category'
];
```

`BookCategory` because book is linked with category through `book_category` table. But how to be with other models?

Answer (score 1):

In a many-to-many relation, BookCategory is consider as a weak entity

You won't need to create model for it

Try this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'book_category', 'book_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book', 'book_category', 'category_id', 'book_id');
    }
}
```

More details see: [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Thank you! You put me on the right track. I found your variant in October docs. Sometimes it's hard to find necessary information there.

Comment: I could output only linked categories of book (as checkbox list). But how to set checked these categories in full checkbox list?

Comment: To get the checkboxes "checked" depends on how you render the "checked" attribute to the HTML input DOM of the checkbox
Do you still need the answer? seems you have a way to implement this in OctoberCMS

Answer (score 0):

I did wrong. Here is solution. I used Builder.

1. Create pivot table (or cross reference table) with 2 fields: `book_id`, `category_id` and set both as **primary key**.
2. In Book model create **relation** field. Don't need write underscore for name. In relation property set name column of category.
3. In Book model file write:

   public $belongsToMany = [
           'categories' => ['mark\myplugin\Models\Category', 'table' => 'mark_myplugin_books_categories']
      ];

That's it! Now categories that you checked will be saved into pivot table and they will be checked in Preview, Update pages.